# Transfering data between View Controllers when having multiple outgoing segues

Tags: objective-c, view, uipopover

I am making a scoreboard app for the iPad.  The app contains a graphic of a grid with five players and with twelve rounds.  I have simply created UITextField's for each score to be entered.  Each of these text field objects can easily be summed and each player will have a total score.  Players are ranked based off their score.  My app is complete as I have explained it.  However when trying to make it more advanced I am running into problems.  Let say I want to enter player 1's score for the first round.  When I click on that box of the grid, I'd like a UIPopover to appear.  The popover brings up a special calculator used to determine the score.  I'd like the result of the calculator to be transferred back to the box I initially clicked on.  I'm having trouble dismissing the UIPopover when the "calculate Score" button is pressed.  If I use a dismiss popover method I can set a specific scoreBox to the result of the calculator, however I need to have a dismiss popover method know which box it should change.  Basically I have a grid containing 60 boxes and each box segues to a calculator view controller.  How do I have that calculator transfer the data back to the box it came from?  Any thoughts? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Prior to displaying the `UIPopoverViewController` you should set a `box` property that references the current box. Then from the `UIPopoverViewController` you can set the text of the `box` prior to dismissing the popover.

Comment: I'm assuming you are referring to something like:

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Player1Round1"])
     {
        self.box = self.player1Round1Score.text;
      }
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Player1Round2"])
    {
       self.box = self.player1Round1Score.text;
    }
    .... // continue for all 60 box options

then when I'm on the calculator View Controller I can say something like
  
  ViewController1 *vc = [[ViewController1 alloc] init]; 
  self.resultOfCalculator.text = vc.box.text

Comment: sorry, I tried typing in a code format and it didn't format.  If I'm understanding correctly you are saying in the prepareForSegue method, I can set the "box" property to the specific box I'm wanting it to change using if statements.  Then when dismissing the popover, I can set the box property to the result of the calculator.  I'm thinking in the above code I should have flipped the last statement to vc.box.text = self.resultsOfCalculator.text; is this correct?

Comment: This is essentially what I meant although there should be a better method than `if` statements. If you are programmatically triggering the segue, you could simply set an instance variable to the `box` which was clicked and then within the `prepareForSegue` method set the `box` property to that.

Comment: thanks for your help so far!  I'm closer than I've been but things aren't quite as I need them.  I tried it with the "if" statements as I've suggested.  Here is what happens:  I click on the player1Round1 score box.  (the prepareForSegue method sets the specific text of that score box to equal my property "box").  Then on my next view controller, I calculate the score using the calculator.  The property "box" gets set to the resultOfCalculator.  Then when the view dismisses the score board is still blank. ...until I click on the player1Round1 button again.. then the score appears

Comment: If you could better explain the `ViewController1 *vc = ...` section of your code, that'd be helpful. Right now it appears you are allocating a new view rather than referencing the main view of your app. I suggest passing a `delegate` property to the popover that references `self`.

Comment: I can see why that happened.  The segue sets the text to the whatever the "box" is set to.  At first it isn't set.  Then when it gets set, nothing will happen until the segue gets triggered again (since the segue sets the text to whatever the "box" is set to).  I need a way to be able to say when the "box" updates, update the text that it is set to.  I don't know about delegates but I have a feeling I need to set a delegate for something like this.  Does this make sense?

Comment: ((RBViewController *) self.presentingViewController).player1Score1.text

that is how I'm referencing my view controllers.  I realized I shouldn't be making a new reference as you've stated.

Comment: I think you should be passing `self.player1Round1Score` rather than its score in the `if`s so that the value can be modified.